# How to create dependent dropdown list using javascript(Reactjs) as frontend and node.js as backend

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

If i select city **A** then it explore Areas in that city.
After I selecting the **area** it also explore **streets** in that area.
After that i select street, It will be stored in my Database

Comment: Have you written any code to attempt this yet? If not, please do so, and then include the code in the question along with details about where it falls short of your expectations from a programmatic standpoint. If yes, include what you've coded already in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your database should be like this:

**Cities**

id - name - other fields

**Areas**

id - name - cityId - other fields

**Streets**

id - name - areaId - other fields

When you want to save the street (let's say you are saving to restaurants table),
then your restaurants table should be like:

**Restaurants**

id - name - streetId - other fields

Only saving the streetId will be enough for you, because from streetId you can get which city or area the street is in. Don't forget to check if streetId exists before saving the restaurant. So that you can send a meaningful response to the client.

On the first load of your web page, you should only get the city list. Once a city is picked, then you should get the area list. Once an area is picked, you should get the street list. Otherwise, it will be too much data to fetch from the database.